# I deleted *apparently* useful XML code in my xcode storyboard - Page View Controller

Tags: xcode

[Highlighted section of what I stupidly deleted...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kpsu.jpg)

So I thought I was a cool dude and thought I could just delete some XML source code to delete a page view controller I didn't want. I readded it to show what I deleted but now I'm getting those dang SIGABRT errors and I think I either didn't delete enough or too much. Any help? I don't want the page view controller anymore and I just want the previously working application to run again.

Comment: Basically you've corrupted the storyboard. If you didn't have a `git` commit that you can revert to, you're hosed. Throw the storyboard away and start over with a new storyboard. Don't look at the storyboard XML ever again.

Comment: Awesome! I did it all and its back to my setup, but I cant seem to connect my UI elements anymore.. I know it's not part of the question, but I cant find anything online